# Jest mock action creator result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, redux, jestjs

My component works fine. The issue is that I'm not able to test the second action creator in my useEffect.

Here's my component:

```
//... some imports here

const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const account = useSelector((state) => state.account);
  const displayName = useSelector((state) => state.displayName);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUserData = async () => {
      const token = await dispatch(updateUserContext());
      
      if (!!token) {
        dispatch(loadUserDetails({ token }));
      }
    };

    fetchUserData();
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
      <div id="app">
       Some stuff here..
     </div>
```

What's not standard here is that I don't dispatch all the data I get from `updateUserContext` action creator. So you can see `token` is just returned back in the component.

And in case we have token we want to run another `loadUserDetails` action creator.

My issue is that I can't set up my test to make `loadUserDetails` run. For now, Jest says  `Expected: {"accessToken": "some-token"} Number of calls: 0`

my test:

```
import Layout from './layout.js';
import { loadUserDetails, logInUser, updateUserContext } from '../store/actions';

jest.mock('react-redux', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react-redux'),
  useDispatch: jest.fn(() => () => {}),
  useEffect: jest.fn((fn) => fn()),
  useSelector: jest.fn((fn) => fn()),
}));
jest.mock('../store/actions', () => ({
  loadUserDetails: jest.fn(),
  logInUser: jest.fn(),
  updateUserContext: jest.fn(),
}));

describe('layout', () => {
  let account;
  let displayName;

  beforeEach(() => {
    account = null;
    displayName = null;
  });

it('returns updateUserContext result', async () => {
    account = { username: 'some-username' };

    useSelector.mockReturnValueOnce(account);
    useSelector.mockReturnValueOnce(displayName);
    updateUserContext.mockResolvedValue("some-token");

    renderComponent();
    const result = await updateUserContext();

    expect(result).toBe("some-token");
  });

  it('calls loadUserDetails with updateUserContext result', async () => {
    account = { username: 'some-username' };

    useSelector.mockReturnValueOnce(account);
    useSelector.mockReturnValueOnce(displayName);
    updateUserContext.mockResolvedValue("some-token");

    renderComponent();
    const result = await updateUserContext();

    expect(loadUserDetails).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ accessToken: result });
  });

const renderComponent = ({ ...rest } = {}) =>
  render( <Layout {...rest}>{<div>some child</div>}</Layout> );
```

The first test passes, but not the second one.

What I see is that in test `updateUserContext` result is set to `some-token`, but it's `undefined` in the component and I suspect that's why it does not go inside the `if statement` I have.

So my question would be how to properly mock the `updateUserContext` result to properly test `loadUserDetails` action creator.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Solved** myself

I forgot about the dispatch layer. So leave it here, maybe will be helpful for someone. The right test would be:

```
it('calls loadUserDetails with updateUserContext result', async () => {
    account = { username: 'some-username' };

    useSelector.mockReturnValueOnce(account);
    useSelector.mockReturnValueOnce(displayName);

    const dispatch = jest.fn(() => 'some-token');
    useDispatch.mockReturnValue(dispatch);

    renderComponent();
    await dispatch(updateUserContext());

    expect(loadUserDetails).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ accessToken: 'some-token' });
  });
```